# Pushing data from angular typescript to chart.js library complication

Tags: html, angular, typescript, chart.js

I have complication in pushing the data that i have compute in typescript component into my chart.js code. when I check it in web interface with the chart.js the data do appear.

[the data appear in the web view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2UJ2.png)

[code I use to call the data in web view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MpZA.png)

but when I use this.october (i.e) into the chart.js code. it didnt appear.

this is the code I used to subscribe and count the data

```
.subscribe((dataChart) => {

    for (const e of dataChart) {
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    var str=e.strRequestDate;   //Set the string in the proper format(best to use ISO format ie YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS)
    var d=new Date(str);  //converts the string into date object
    // console.log(d)
    var m=d.getMonth(); //get the value of month
    //console.log(monthNames[m]) // Print the month name
    
      if (monthNames[m] === "January"){
        this.January++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "February"){
        this.February++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "March"){
        this.March++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "April"){
        this.April++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "May"){
        this.May++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "June"){
        this.June++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "July"){
        this.July++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "August"){
        this.August++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "September"){
        this.September++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "October"){
        this.October++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "November"){
        this.November++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "December"){
        this.December++
      }
    
    }
    // console.log(this.January) //checking if the value properly generated

    },
    (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    }
  );
 }
```

this is the code for chart.js within the same component with API that I count.

```
ngOnInit() {
var myChart = new Chart("myChart", {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          //labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
          labels: ['October', 'November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March'],
          datasets: [{
              label: 'Monthly Record of IT SIR Request',
              data: [this.October, this.November, this.December, this.January, this.February, this.March], <== this data return 0 in the chart
              backgroundColor: [
                   'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                   'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                   'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                   'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                   'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 0, 153, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(102, 255, 153, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 51, 0, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(204, 0, 204, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(0, 153, 153, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                   'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                   'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                   'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                   'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                   'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                   'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 0, 153, 1)',
                  'rgba(102, 255, 153, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 51, 0, 1)',
                  'rgba(204, 0, 204, 1)',
                  'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(0, 153, 153, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true
                  }
              }]
          }
      }
})
}
```

lastly this is the error that i screenshot

[All returning 0 as value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73ptB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. i need to write the code within the subscribe in order for me to reuse the data that i have manipulate for the chart.js

this is the answer on how to make it work:

```
.subscribe((dataChart) => {

    for (const e of dataChart) {
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    var str=e.strRequestDate;   //Set the string in the proper format(best to use ISO format ie YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS)
    var d=new Date(str);  //converts the string into date object
    // console.log(d)
    var m=d.getMonth(); //get the value of month
    //console.log(monthNames[m]) // Print the month name
    
      if (monthNames[m] === "January"){
        this.January++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "February"){
        this.February++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "March"){
        this.March++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "April"){
        this.April++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "May"){
        this.May++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "June"){
        this.June++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "July"){
        this.July++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "August"){
        this.August++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "September"){
        this.September++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "October"){
        this.October++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "November"){
        this.November++
      }

      if (monthNames[m] === "December"){
        this.December++
      }
    
    }
    
    var myChart = new Chart("myChart", {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: ['October 2020', 'November 2020', 'December 2020', 'January 2021', 'February 2021', 'March 2021'],
          datasets: [{
              label: 'Monthly Record of IT SIR Request',
              data: [this.October, this.November, this.December, this.January, this.February, this.March],
              backgroundColor: [
                   'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                   'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                   'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                   'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                   'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 0, 153, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(102, 255, 153, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 51, 0, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(204, 0, 204, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(0, 153, 153, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                   'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                   'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                   'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                   'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                   'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                   'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 0, 153, 1)',
                  'rgba(102, 255, 153, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 51, 0, 1)',
                  'rgba(204, 0, 204, 1)',
                  'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(0, 153, 153, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true
                  }
              }]
          }
      }

  })

    },
```